# Event validation: Allow __doPostBack for one control and *any* arguments

Tags: .net, asp.net, eventvalidation

I'm using

```
__doPostBack(clientIdOfSomeButton, someData);
```

to create a PostBack in JavaScript. The problem is that `someData` is not known in advance, and event validation kicks in because I cannot `ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation` *every* possible value of `someData`.

So far, I can see only two possibilities to solve this problem:

1. Turn off event validation for the page, which is not recommended for security reasons.
2. Instead of passing the data via event validation, put the data in some hidden text field via JavaScript and then call `__doPostBack`. That's ugly.

Is there some third option that I've missed? Ideally, I'd like something like `ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidationIgnoreArguments(myButton)`, but something like this does not exist...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someData is not known in advance then how does the server know the meaning of the postback?  The second argument is to indicate the type of event or specific information concerning the event, not a user inputted value.

I would register for a custom argument and pass the someData another way.

```
ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation(clientIdOfSomeButton, "CustomEvent");
```

And on the client

Html

```
<input name="customArgument" type="hidden" value="" />
```

Javascript

```
document.forms[0].customArgument = someData;
__doPostBack(clientIdOfSomeButton, '');
```

then retrieve your value

```
if(Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"] == "customArgument")
{
   var customArgument = Request["customArgument"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up using (with an <asp:Hidden> instead of a standard HTML input). It's similar to option 2 mentioned in my question, but the <input> is cleaner than an invisible textbox.